# How to print a different value from a list in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a Discord bot and one of the features that I wanted to add, was to pick a random item from a list and post it. After some time, pick a new item from the same list and post.

The [Discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/async/examples) github has an example for doing loops/background tasks.

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await client.send_message(channel, counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('token')
```

The code above works fine. The bot logs in a keeps counting up. Here's how I tried to change it.

```
import discord
import asyncio
import random

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    postimage = random.choice(list(open('imgdb.txt'))) #Opens my list of urls and then pick one from there.
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
    while not client.is_closed:
     await client.send_message(channel, postimage)
     await asyncio.sleep(10) # task runs every 10 seconds for testing

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('token')
```

The problem is that, the bot will pick one image at random and then continue posting the same image over and over again. How do I force post image to be different every loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the value of `postimage` before each sending.

```
async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
    while not client.is_closed:
        postimage = random.choice(list(open('imgdb.txt'))) # Open my list of urls and then pick one from there.
        await client.send_message(channel, postimage)
        await asyncio.sleep(10) # Run every 10 seconds for testing
```

Comment: That is logical, the `choice` function is only called once (before the `while` loop).
Try the above code.

Comment: I'm not actually sure why moving `postimage` outside matters but that fixed it! Thanks a lot dude.